# Relationship between Amalek and Gog/Magog?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, messianic-redemption

Both are mentioned as adversaries of the Jewish people, and are mentioned in various sources, but always separately. Amalek is first mentioned in [Shemot Ch 17](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and several times in Neviim, while Gog and Magog are mentioned in [Ezekiel Ch 38](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.38?lang=bi).

Is there any sort of relationship between them ? Are they somehow related, or is one descended from the other ? Will the Jewish people have to face both before the Messianic Age ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only found one relevant source at the moment:

The Pri Tzaddik writes on [Nasso 15:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pri_Tzadik%2C_Nasso.15.2?vhe=Pri_Tzaddik,_Lublin,_1901&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...ואחר כל זה יהיה עוד מלחמת גוג ומגוג על משיח בן יוסף כי גומ"ג הוא מזרע עמלק..."

Translation: "...and after all of this there will still be the war of Gog and Magog upon Mashiach ben Yosef for Gog and Magog is of the lineage of Amalek..."

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it has provided the most reliable source I have seen so far.

Answer (score 4):

They are definitely not related, as Magog is [listed](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.10.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) among the sons of Japheth, the son of Noah. Amalek is [listed](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.36.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as a grandson of Esau, who was descended from Noah's son Shem.

Comment: Maybe they're related on their mom's sides?

Comment: Possibly, but that wouldn't make them one nation. They might be linked in other ways.

Comment: I don't know about "one nation" or not, but "They are definitely not physically related" is a pretty strong claim and seems unfounded.

Comment: I took out the physically.

Comment: There's also the issue of timing. Magog being a the son of Japeth and the grandson of Noah is much, much earlier in the timeline of Bereshit than Esau from whom Amalek is descended. Amalek from what I recall is not even mentioned in Bereshit, the first mention being in Shemot when they attacked the israelites.

The point I'm trying to make here is even though there is no proof they are related, there is no proof to the contrary either. If Magog himself had sons and daughters which could have mingled to produce Amalek.

Comment: Amalek is in Bereshit at the link in my answer.